# Android detecting OnPageChangeListener on a ViewPager from within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Hi i have a ViewPager that has creates a fragment for each page using a fragment adapter. On each fragment i have an ImageView that i want to animate everytime that page appears on screen.

My ViewPager currently preloads the 1st 2 pages so the animation doesn't run on those but it does work on the 3rd page. I have added an onPageChangedListener but not sure how to implement it so it talks to my fragment adapter and runs the animation. Does anyone know either how to correctly detect a page change from within a fragment or a way to disable the page preloading
in a memory management efficient way?

heres what i have tried so far

heres my activity with the ViewPager

```
public void getAdapter(){
         CustomViewPager pager = (CustomViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tutorialPager);
         pager.setPagingEnabled(true);
         pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(-1);
         adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),this);
         pager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
         CirclePageIndicator Indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.circles);
         Indicator.setViewPager(pager);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_tutorial_view);
        getAdapter();
        extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    }


        public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

            private Context context;

            public MyPagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager,Context c) {

                super(fragmentManager);
                context = c;
            }


            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                int levelCount = 4;
                return levelCount;
            }

            // Returns the fragment to display for that page
            @Override
            public TutorialAdapter getItem(int position) {
                String data = null;

                return TutorialAdapter.newInstance(position, data, context);

            }


            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                return "Page " + position;
            }

        }

       public static class onPageChangedListener implements OnPageChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

       }

    }
```

heres my fragment adapter inside my onCreateView

```
if(page == 1){
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_tutorial, container, false);


                tutImage = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.tutImage);
                int imageResource = getResources().getIdentifier("tut_view_2", "drawable", context.getPackageName());
                Drawable tutImageDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    tutImage.setBackground(tutImageDrawable);
                }else{
                    tutImage.setBackgroundDrawable(tutImageDrawable);
                }

                Animation AniMoveUp = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.tut_image);  
                tutImage.startAnimation(AniMoveUp);
```

Comment: I would put the Fragments in a List, keep a reference to the list in the Activity, and, in onPageSelected, get the custom Fragment from the list at the given position and call the animation method on the custom Fragment.  Remember to return the right Fragment in getItem of your custom Adapter, too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example Android application that extends the Fragment Life Cycle with two new methods:  onResumeViewPage() and onPauseViewPage().   If you put your animation code in  onResumeViewPage() it should work.

See: [Slider Android Application](https://fishjd@bitbucket.org/fishjd/slider.git) in BitBucket.

Answer (score -1):

Move your startAnimation call to the onResume method of the Fragments. That way the animation will start when the Fragment is visible. See [Fragment LifeCycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Lifecycle) for more detailed explanation.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure when onResume is called in a ViewPager, though.  I would not say this is safe to assume.  Besides, onResume will get called lots of times, not just when he selects that page in the ViewPager.  This is not the solution.